# Can W3C DOM be used to create Document/DocType nodes?

Tags: html, dom, w3c, doctype

I'm curious if there is a way to create DocType nodes via W3C DOM? The spec explicitly states that they are readonly and cannot be edited, but are they able to be created?

> http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-412266927

The Document interface doesn't seem to have any create method for it:

> http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#i-Document

Perhaps the broader question is: Can an entirely new HTML Document be built programmatically via DOM? I know about `document.createDocumentFragment()` but I mean the equivalent of a root HTML document with specific doctype, etc.

---

**Update:** it looks like recent Gecko and WebKit implement `DOMImplementation.createDocument` and `DOMImplementation.createDocumentType` but not IE8 or before (haven't checked IE9). So unfortunately I'm still stuck there.

I am also a bit unsure what I can do with this new Document instance once I have it. All of the current DOM methods hang off the global document object, so there doesn't seem to be a way to swap it with a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a DOMImplementation object. See the section [Bootstrapping](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#Bootstrap).

Comment: I'm not seeing how that answers my question. The `DOMImplementation` object appears to allow you to query the supported DOM modules. Can you be more specific about how one could use this to create new instances of these nodes?

Comment: DOMImplementation (http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-102161490) has methods createDocument and createDocumentType.

Comment: Ah okay, so it looks like you can get one of those objects from `document.implementation`. Can you replace the current document with one created this way?

Comment: Although I've seen web pages use document.implementation, I've never used it myself, so sorry I don't know. Do you want to replace the current document permanently or swap backwards and forwards between 2 or more documents? You might be better off starting a new question.

Comment: Thanks. This is the new question about replacing the current document: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4297877