# Replace html element entirely using JavaScript (no libraries)

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on embedded WKWebView (a browser view on iOS), so I don't want/can't use any libraries and need to achieve the following purely in JavaScript.

While content of the web view is loading, I want to clear previous content, and display something like "Loading...".

The most obvious way is to

```
document.body.innerHTML = "Loading...";
```

(method 1)

But the problem is it leaves other elements (e.g. scripts, styles) of the page intact, while I need the style to be reset (e.g. clear background, fonts, etc)

There is a way to clear everything by removing HTML element, which is good

```
document.documentElement.remove()
```

(method 2)

But how can I then add a new HTML element with new content?

So is there a way to add a new HTML element using method 2, or to clear style, scripts, etc using method 1?

Note: `Loading...` is just an example text I want to use, actual content could be proper HTML if it's important.

Comment: Do you need to clear the content? For example we have a `popup` div that will display and hide all else. Would that suffice?

Comment: Why exactly do you want to do it this way? why not implement something like a `modal window`?

Comment: I don't know which site is loaded, so who knows how those popups are styled?

Comment: @ Bhojendra Rauniyar it;'s a good idea to read a question before you mark it as duplicate. I was NOT asking how to clear content, I was asking how to load new content.

Comment: Plus, there are much better duplicates: [What other options for replacing entire HTML document via W3C DOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4297877/215552), [Replacing Entire Page Including Head Using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4292603/215552), [Replace entire HTML document in-place](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2825586/215552)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```js
document.documentElement.remove();

var html = document.createElement('html');
var body = document.createElement('body');

html.appendChild(body);
document.appendChild(html);

document.body.innerHTML = `<span>Here your arbitrary html</span>`;
```

```html
<div>x</div>
```

Comment: perfect, this is doing exactly what I need. Bonus for end-to-end solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Store the nodes and show loading

```
var head = document.head.innerHTML;
var body = document.body.innerHTML;
document.head.innerHTML = '';
document.body.innerHTML = 'Loading...';
```

undo

```
document.head.innerHTML = head;
document.body.innerHTML = body;
```

This way you can show the loading stuff.